# Encrypting two partitions using TrueCrypt

Tags: partitioning, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption

Is it possible to encrypt both the windows system partition and a data partition, without encrypting the whole harddisk, using truecrypt?

It's because the haddisk has other partitions with Fedora Linux and they can't be encrypted together with windows using TrueCrypt, so I'll have to encrypt them seperatly.

Is is possible to encrypt both of these windows partitions, so they are mounted on boot, or do I have to put it all in one partition.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use TrueCrypt to encrypt whichever individual partitions you want.  Follow the instructions in the tutorial (http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/tutorial).  For the Windows partition, choose "Encrypt the system partition" in step 3.  For the data partition, choose "Encrypt a non-system partition" in step 3.  Use the same passphrase for both partitions.

Once you have encrypted your Windows partition and your data partition, you can follow the instructions in the FAQ to mount the data partition automatically on boot (http://www.truecrypt.org/faq).

> **Can I configure TrueCrypt to mount automatically whenever Windows starts a non-system TrueCrypt volume that uses the same password as my system partition/drive (i.e. my pre-boot authentication password)?**
>
> Yes. To do so, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Mount the volume (to the drive letter to which you want it to be mounted every time).
> 2. Right-click the mounted volume in the drive list in the main TrueCrypt window and select 'Add to System Favorites'.
> 3. The System Favorites Organizer window should appear now. In this window, enable the option 'Mount system favorite volumes when Windows starts' and click OK.

Comment: It doesn't mount automatically when I do as written in the FAQ. I've tried enabling "Cache pre-boot authentication password in driver memory (for mounting of non-system volumen)" in System -> Settings, but that didn't change anything either. Any ideas?

Comment: When you choose Favorites -> Mount Favorite Volumes, does it mount the drive successfully (without asking for a password)?

Comment: No, nothing happens.

Comment: However, when I click "Auto-Mount Devices" it does ask for the password and mounts.