# TrueCrypt System Favorite Volume doesn't mount automatically on boot

Tags: partitioning, encryption, mount, truecrypt

I've encrypted my system partition using TrueCrypt and I've read that I can mount my encrypted data partition (TrueCrypt volume) on boot by making it a "System Favorite" and giving it the same password as the system partition. However it doesn't work and I have to mount it manually every time.

See [this example](https://superuser.com/questions/359531/encrypting-two-partitions-using-truecrypt).

I've tried enabling "Cache pre-boot authentication password in driver memory (for mounting of non-system volumes)" in `System` -> `Settings`, but that didn't change anything either.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, I'm currently struggling with exactly the same issue. At some point I got it working but it ignored the assigned drive letters; now it's broken again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care, that you use a english keyboard-Layout when setting the passwort for the volume. 
(because the pre-boot-auth-password will be typed with english keybord)

Comment: How does this solve it not mounting?

Answer (score 2):

In my Windows 8 I need to reboot my computer before system favorites mount.

At the first boot, the system favorites are not mounting, but on reboot do. It is very strange and I assume it is some kind of bug in Truecrypt 7a.

I guess I could take all my system favorites and convert them to normal favorites; then I can manually mount them after booting. But since some start-up programs already created some havoc by then, I always go the reboot route. So type in your password on boot, after loading select restart, type in your password again and then everything works as it should.

It's a nuisance, obviously, but it works.

Comment: One possible explanation is that Windows 8 use a feature called "Hybrid boot and shutdown" which prevent Truecrypt mouting favorite system volumes. It can be disabled by following instructions [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-hybrid-boot-and-shutdown-in-windows-8/)